# How to real time update pages and also save jquery updates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using this code atm

```
<form id="love" name="love" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
  Name: <input id="name" type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="update">
    <thead>
        <th>User</th>
        <th>Bet Amount</th>
        <th>Payout</th>
        <th>Game</th>
        <th>Roll</th>
        <th>Profit</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <script type="text/javascript">

  $("#love").submit(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'response.php',
      data: {   username: $('#name').val() },
      success: function (data) {
        $("#update").prepend(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
  });

</script>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

//Response.PHP

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$username</td>";
echo "</tr>";
?>
```

What this code does is, when someone enters a query, a new row with the name he entered gets added to the table. The problem is,

1. On refresh, the data is lost. (i.e., it only updates it for the client).
2. It isn't shown to other users (since it's only for the client)

What can I do to get it to update for all users online and also not lose the data on refresh (i.e, update data for the server)

Thanks

Comment: Use a database on the server and post to it.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you will need to modify your Response.php to include following:

1. Save new username to database.
2. Pick existing users from database.
3. Return all the users obtained from Database.

   ```
   $username = isset($_GET['username'])? $_GET['username'] : NULL;

     if($username) {
          //save new user to database  
     }

   //STEP2. pick all the users from database

   //STEP3. return all the users obtained from Databse.

   ?>
   ```

Since you cannot make push requests to browser from php, you will need to call the following js in interval of 2 mins (configurable):

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'response.php',
      data: {},
      success: function (data) {
        $("#update").html(data);
      },
      error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError);
      }
    });
```

You can achieve this by the help of setInterval() function in javascript.

NOTE: I have just described the concept as to how to achieve the solution, you need to write the code for yourself. Let me know if you still face problem with this.

Comment: Thansk for the answer. But is there a way to do it without using databases? it can become very resource hungry this way

Comment: If you like you can store the data in JSON file or XML file and skip using database.

Comment: Alright I will test it and come back to you, in a while. Going for lunch and stuff as of now